# LaptopModelManager for WirelessHost in callInitialize()

Tags: omnet++, inet

I'm using Inet framework and I'd like to create several wireless hosts dynamically during the simulation. For this purpose I used LaptopModelManager class, but when I get to this line: mod->callInitialize() in the LaptopModelManager::newNode method I face the segmentation fault:

Thread 1 "myNets" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff74358d7 in inet::visualizer::MobilityCanvasVisualizer::receiveSignal (this=0x34f2540, source=0x7240fe0, signal=95, object=0x7240fe0, details=0x0) at inet/visualizer/mobility/MobilityCanvasVisualizer.cc:126
126         entry->visualization->setTransform(cFigure::Transform().translate(position.x, position.y));

Here is what I have in my ini file:

```
**.laptopModelManager.NumNodes = 3
**.laptopModelManager.startLife = uniform(2s,3s)
**.laptopModelManager.endLife = uniform(6s,8s)
**.laptopModelManager.nodeType = "inet.node.inet.WirelessHost"
**.laptopModelManager.nodeName = "cliHostGuest"
```

And in my ned file I added the node with @dynamic:

```
cliHostGuest[n]: WirelessHost {
            parameters:
                @dynamic;
                @display("p=444,178");
                //mobilityType = "LinearMobility";
}
```

What is the problem? Any help is really appreciated, I tried so many things but can't get out of this error.

Many thanks

Comment: Could you provide the source code for the signal you send/receive? It looks like you have a memory bug, where some data is passed to the visualization and you're free-ing or otherwise removing that same data. Maybe you're passing a pointer to a local variable from a method that returns before the visualization is done?

Answer (score 0):

@RensvanderHeijden Thanks for your response.

Here is the part of code that creates new node:

```
cModule* parentmod = getParentModule();
int nodeVectorIndex = index;
if (!parentmod) error("Parent Module not found");

cModuleType* nodeType = cModuleType::get(type);
if (!nodeType) error("Module Type \"%s\" not found", type);

//TODO: this trashes the vectsize member of the cModule, although nobody seems to use it
cModule* mod = nodeType->create(name, parentmod, nodeVectorIndex, nodeVectorIndex);
mod->finalizeParameters();
mod->buildInside();
mod->scheduleStart(simTime());

if (setCoor)
{
    MobilityBase* mm = NULL;
    for (cModule::SubmoduleIterator iter(mod); !iter.end(); iter++) {
        cModule* submod = iter();
        mm = dynamic_cast<MobilityBase*>(submod);
        if (!mm)
            continue;
        mm->par("initialX").setDoubleValue(position.x);
        mm->par("initialY").setDoubleValue(position.y);
        mm->par("initialZ").setDoubleValue(position.z);
        break;
    }
    if (!mm)
        error("Mobility modele not found");
}
NodeInf info;
info.endLife = endLife;
info.module = mod;
nodeList[index] = info;
mod->callInitialize();
```

And here you can find the entire class:

https://github.com/aarizaq/inetmanet-3.x/blob/inetmanet-2.2/src/mobility/single/LaptopModelManager.cc

If I don't call the last line (mod->callInitialize()), the node will be visualized but do nothing more. And when I perform the callInitialize() this error happens.

Your answer seems right to me, but still don't understand how to fix it.